# Time conversion in UNIX/LINUX

Tags: time, conversion

I need to convert a unix timestamp *(number of seconds since 2000)* into a standard human-readable format. I found that the command 
`date -d @392603388.257982` works like a charm but the default start date is 1970.

Comment: What is the issue you're experiencing? Unix timstamps are offsets since 1970.

Comment: Do you want this on Unix or on Linux? They are not the same thing and, specifically, the `date` command is very different. Since you're using `date -d`, I assume you mean Linux and not Unix. If so, please [edit] your question and remove "UNIX" from the title since it is misleading. That said, as mentioned by Kusalananda, there is no such thing as a Unix timestamp expressed as seconds since 2000. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Perhaps you need to add 946684800 seconds?

Answer (score 4):

A linux timestamp ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)) is counted since 1st January 1970. Where did the year 2000 come from? Is it a homework? If yes, then you could use `date` but simply increase given timestamp (counted from 2000) by number of seconds that passed until year 2000 (I got it with following command: `date -u +"%s" -d "1/1/2000"`).

EDIT:
Och, and look out for time zone, that's why I've added `-u` switch above.

Answer (score 1):

If your timestamp number is in seconds, you could just add it to `2000-01-01T00:00:00`.  With GNU date that's as simple as

```
date -d "2001-01-01Z +$n seconds"
```

I've included a `Z` there to indicate that your epoch is specified in Zulu (UTC) time - if your epoch is actually in local time, you should omit that.